Open adf-document-list's context menu on click instead of right click
I am using  ADF 6.10 (Alfresco Content App), Alfresco Content Services 23.2.
I have found that Alfresco file list component (files.component.html), that have adf-document-list component which opens context menu on right click,
<adf-document-list
      #documentList
      acaDocumentList
      acaContextActions
      [selectionMode]="'multiple'"
      [multiselect]="true"
      [currentFolderId]="node?.id"
      [loading]="true"
      [showHeader]="showHeader"
      [node]="nodeResult"
      [allowDropFiles]="true"
      [navigate]="false"
      [sorting]="['name', 'asc']"
      [imageResolver]="imageResolver"
      [headerFilters]="true"
      [filterValue]="queryParams"
      [isResizingEnabled]="true"
      [blurOnResize]="false"
      (node-dblclick)="handleNodeClick($event)"
      (name-click)="handleNodeClick($event)"
      (filterSelection)="onFilterSelected($event)"
      (error)="onError()"
    >

It's using directive acaContextActions which is having HostListener which opens context menu on right click
@HostListener('contextmenu', ['$event'])

onContextMenuEvent(event: MouseEvent) {
if (event) {
event.preventDefault();
  if (this.enabled) {
    const target = this.getTarget(event);
    if (target) {
      this.execute(event, target);
    }
  }
}

}
I tried by putting click event HostListener - @HostListener('click', ['$event']), but it is not working properly.
It opens context menu but it blocks the multiselect feature of file / folder selection because it's listen click event and prevents the checkbox events.
It also sometimes opens contextmenu but it takes the wrong row / node reference and opens context menu of other nodes.
I also tried with mousedown event as well but none of them are working properly.
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])

onContextMenuClickEvent(event: MouseEvent) {
if (event.which !== 3) {
event.preventDefault();
if (this.enabled) {
const target = this.getTargetFromEvent(event);
if (target) {
if (this.isEmptyTable(target)) {
return null;
}
this.execute$.next(event);
}
}
}
}
I wanted to implement the same behaviour of conext menu as we got the menu items on right click by doing a click.
Please help / suggest the customization or changes required to achieve this solution.
I also asked same question on Alfresco Community Hub
Thanks,
Vikash
